# rdlc - phantom page break, what to check?

Tags: rdlc

I have a RDLC report which has some controls on the first page, which are inside a rectangle and which display ok. Beneath the rectangle, i have a matrix, which spans more than one page both in width and in height. I want the matrix to start rendering on the second page. If I enable "insert break before" on the matrix, there is an extra blank page before the matrix(in print layout), which is my problem. If I reduce the amount of data, so the matrix does not span more than one page in width, there is no blank page, and all is well. I checked the Page and Body sizes, they are ok. Any tips? This has been driving me crazy all day, what can I check? Thx

Answer (score 10):

I know this is probably too late now, but I was receiving extra page breaks if my **Body** size width property was greater than my **Report** PageSize width property.

Check both these things.

Comment: never late, still can reference by other people like me :P

Answer (score 2):

Put borders on everything to see if they are wider than the page. Check the `keepTogether` property on all the elements to see if they are creating extra white-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the 'insert break before' on a dummy rectangle between your first page content and the matrix, instead of giving it directly on the matrix itself.