# RDLC VS2010 1) how to prevent a group from splitting and keep a group on one page 2) prevent blank pages appearing everyother page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc, report

For my RDLC report I am using a table, which have around 15 cells. Each cell can vary in height.
the data have been bind  to a report class i have created.
When i run my query i can get  about 1 to 15 tables in a report, i am having couple of issues with it,

**first issue** is, the data over flow in the table and ends up splitting up the table to a couple of pages.what i would like to see happen is the whole table gets moved to a new page rather than half of it.I tried grouping the table, set the options to true for "keep together" but nothing seems to work...

**my second issue** is every other page is blank, i tried changing the margins but nothing seems to work.....

any RDLC experts out there who can help????

ADR

Comment: Check out GONeale answer over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7088741/107452
It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

try to put every table in a rectangle and put the keep together in the property
of the rectangle
keep the page in the prportaional maby you are sliding to the other page 
so you can fill the border

Comment: well i sorted all these issues using a different method, by using crystal report . seriously if anybody who are contemplating on taking the RDLC route... DON'T!!!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because size of the report and size of the report body does not match.
To resolve this, click on blank space in the left side of the report and see properties. If your report is 8.5 X 11 in and 1in margin both sides, than report body width shouldn't be more than 6.5 in.